# Create new transaction off existing ARB -authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I have members signing up on my website creating an "ARB" so they pay monthly.... i then call them and upsell services which may be a completely different price and they are one time....

So if i have a guy paying $9.99 a month (ARB) then my sales team gets him to agree to a $300 service.. how do i charge him a one time charge from the ARB? Do i create a new ARB but somehow make it only charge one month?

The whole point is to not ask the client for the credit card again, can someone help me?
 Is this what CIM is because i dont have that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with ARB. It's for consistent recurring payments: same amount over a set period of time. If you want the ability to go back and charge a customer without getting their credit card information again you will need to use CIM which lets you create payment profiles to charge against. Otherwise you'll have to get their credit card information again and then you can use AIM for that one time payment.

Comment: Will this have to be coded at all in order to utilize CIM>? If i enabled the CIM which is ($20/m from authorize.net) and someone signs up for $29.99 on my site, can i go into their ARB subscription and click something like charge this person or maybe go into another dashboard that lists my customers with their CC's and just charge them whatever number, not affecting their existing ARB's? I record the customers conversations with their consent and other times sign contracts so everything is done legally. Thanks John

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be backwards compatible with your current subscriptions. The amount of code you'd need to write would depend on whether or not you kept using ARB or not. If you don't you'll need to write your own subscription engine since CIM doesn't do any actual billing for you. If you use both CIM and ARB then you will only need to code the parts that allow you to utilize the CIM functionality you need.

Comment: i know this is old but you can now seem to be able to create a CIM profile from an existing ARB subscription. http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Ideas/ARB-and-CIM-Interoperability/idi-p/48449